# Ajax Request In Order

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, file-get-contents

I'm making litte app to get pages by URL and check their title. 
I need check URLs line by line which is user pasted in textarea.
Process sequence :
Check URL > append response to page > then check next url......
Here is my code :

HTML :

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="urlLine"></textarea>
<button type="button" name="action" id="check">Check IT!</button>
```

Js :

```
 function getResp(req) {

    var uri = req.shift();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'r.php',
        async: true,
        data: {'uriLine': uri},
        success: function (msg) {
            $('.collection').append(msg);
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: height,
            }, 500)
        },
        fail: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });

    if (typeof uri !== 'undefined' && uri.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(getResp, 5, req);
    } else {
       alert('Finish');
    }
  }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').click(function () {
       var uris= $('textarea').val().split('\n');
        getResp(uris);

    });
```

PHP :

```
sleep(5); // I don't know why i'm adding. Just wait for performance.
$title = 'title_i_searching';
$adress = $_POST['uriLine'];
if($check->chekURL('https://'.$adress) == $title){
echo ' OK';
}else{
echo 'NOT OK';
}
```

PHP CLASS :

```
class checkES
 {
 public  $url;
 public function chekURL($url){
    $arrContextOptions=array(
        "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
        "http"=>array(
            "timeout"=> 5
        )
    );
$str=
file_get_contents($url,false,stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); 
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}

public function parseByLine($content){

    $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $content);
    return $lines;
}
}
```

But when i run this code for example; in 20 URL searching on 5th url page alert 'finish'. But append function still continue. 
Sometimes, page crash down.

I could not find the healthy method.

I wish i was explain. Sorry for bad language.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the code to process next uri in  `success` function like this:

```
function getResp(req) {

    var uri = req.shift();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'r.php',
        async: true,
        data: {'uriLine': uri},
        success: function (msg) {
            $('.collection').append(msg);
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: height,
            }, 500);
            if (typeof uri !== 'undefined' && uri.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(getResp, 5, req);
            } else {
               alert('Finish');
            }
        },
        fail: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
}
```